# display images with different names and different extensions (PHP)

Tags: php, glob

I'm trying to call images with their Id row as name, each images as different extensions (jpg, gif, svg...) and I want to take the image with its Id without write the extension every time. I saw I can do it with a GLOB but I don't really know how.
For now, I'm here :

```
<?php
  $ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "svg", "png");
    foreach($ext as $extension){
      if( is_file($row->id. '.' .$extension)){
        echo '<img src="'.$row->id. '.' .$extension.'"/>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you save the image name without extension you have to check if the file exists afterwards. Thats obviously a fail in your data model?

Comment: No, I save the image name with extension every time, I just want to call images without writing name extension in my database, I want to display it automatically